# How to prevent Emacs from duplicating shell commands?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs

I always use Emacs's shell. I create 2 buffers (`C-x 2`) and use one of them as a terminal (`M-x shell`).

Sometimes I use a command a lot of times (e. g. `python3` `test.py`). I use shortcut `<C-up>` to repeat the last command. And it's very inconvenient that Emacs saves duplicates of commands. I have to press `<C-up>` many times so that I can run any other command.

The problems is only in Emacs's shell. I have setting `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` in `.bashrc` and in usual terminal it works very well.

Is it possible to configure Emacs so that it ignores duplicates?

Comment: Check out M-r (ALT+r) to look up a previous command quickly by searching

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's customizable

```
(setq comint-input-ignoredups t)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Setting 'comint-input-ignoredups' as suggested by Jürgen Hötzel will of course solve the immediate, but here are some alternatives.

You could choose to use the command 'ansi-term' instead of 'shell', this will run a bash (or whatever you choose) so you get the same control as in (say) an xterm. As an added bonus, you also get a rather capable terminal so applications that depend on this will work.

Another possibility, if you have something you want to repeatedly run, is to use the 'compile' command. This can run any shell command, it does not have to be a compiler. The advantage here is that you keep the running of the test out of your shell command history (no matter how you run your shell) and you get the output in a separate buffer. If the output is suitably organised and/or the compilation buffer is suitably configured, you could also use the 'next-error' command to jump back to the appropriate part of the source.

Finally, I would like to mention that the 'shell' command supports searching the command history. It is by default bound to M-r (comint-history-isearch-backward-regexp).

Comment: Quite interesting as well. Thanks!